# Autocomplete input from item of an array

Tags: bash

I am working to build a script that will ask a question to the user, for example:

What's your pet?

And I have a list of animals that is currently stored in an array.
I am looking for a way to allow to add an autocomplete during the user input, for example, if the user types "eleph" and press tab the autocomplete will type elephant.

Is it possible to implement something like this without using arguments (as the answer will need to be done while the script is already running) ?

Many thanks!

Comment: `without using parameters` Parameters to? I would use `fzf`.

Comment: Sorry I meant arguments

Comment: Arguments to?  What do you mean by "without arguments"? How does arguments affect a running script?

Comment: I am just specifying that I need this to run without arguments as all the examples I have seen so far are to actually autocomplete a bash command, while I need to autocomplete a text input

Comment: cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278666/333919